# Loader for SimpleComboBox - GXT

Tags: gwt, gxt

I want to create a Dynamic ComboBox i.e it fetches data from DB

On pressing some buttons(on other Panels) I want to reload the ComboBox.

ComboBox Store Datatype : List
I created an RPC call(RPCProxy) which fetches List

However I cannot create a Loader to map it to my ComboBox Store, as Loader is mapped only to a Store that Extends BeanModel instance.
So I can fetch data only once while loading, but I cant refetch data, as I cant use a loader.

Here is some part of Code:

SimpleComboBox myCombo = new SimpleComboBox();
List myStore = new ArrayList();

```
XX.getService().getMyDD(userData.getId(), weekOffset, new AsyncCallback<List<String>>() {
                    public void onFailure(
                            Throwable caught) {
                        MessageBox.alert(UIConstants.ERROR,caught.getMessage(),
                                        null);
                    }
                    public void onSuccess(List<String> result) {
                        for(String str: result)
                        {
                            myStore.add(str);                               
                        }
                        myCombo.removeAll();
                        myCombo.add(myStore);
                        myCombo.setSimpleValue(UIConstants.ALL);
                    }
                });

        RpcProxy<List<String>> userTypeProxy = new RpcProxy<List<String>>() {
            @Override
            protected void load(Object loadConfig,
                    AsyncCallback<List<String>> callback) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("In Loader: my: "+my);
                    XX.getService().getMyDD(userData.getId(), weekOffset, 
                             callback);     
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    MessageBox.alert(UIConstants.ERROR,
                            UIConstants.ERROR_USER_RETRIEVED, null);
                }
            }
        };
```

Please let me know if I can implement any type of loader for my ComboBox, like ListLoader etc.
I highly appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: u can use as List<ModelData> list = new ArrayList<ModelData>() and populate data. callback.onSuccess(new BaseListLoadResult<ModelData>(list));

Comment: Hi swamy, thanks for your help. I have done that, but even then the ComboBox doesnt get populated on screen. However after calling loader the Store gets updated correctly, but not on screen.